# Vex dialog input: conditional show or hide text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Vex to show a dialog. I need to conditional show or hide the text inside input.

I have this:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) { 

 $('.w-more').click(function(){
  
  var quota_ini = $(this).data('w-userquota');
  var quota_current = $(this).data('w-quota');   
     
     vex.dialog.open({
      message: 'Hola!',      
      input: [
       'Cantidad actual: '+quota_ini+'€<br>',
       'Cantidad apostada: '+quota_current +'€<br>'
      ].join('')
     });
 });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/2.3.4/css/vex-theme-os.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/2.3.4/css/vex.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vex-js/2.3.4/js/vex.combined.min.js"></script>

<div class='w-more' data-w-userquota="0" data-w-quota="20">Click</div>
```

I need something like this:

```js
$('.more').click(function(){  
   
  var quota_ini = $(this).data('w-userquota');
  var quota_current = $(this).data('w-quota'); 

  vex.dialog.open({
    message: 'Hola!',      
    input: [       
      if (quota_ini>0) {'Cuota actual: '+quota_ini+'<br>'},
      if (quota_current>0) {'Cuota actual: '+quota_current+'<br>'}
    ].join('')
  });

});
```

Any ideas? or there is any modal alternative to do this?

Comment: can you give a working example?

Comment: Added to question